# How to access the files which is aws /var/www/html via browser

Tags: php, linux, zend-framework, amazon-web-services, eclipse-pdt

I'm using the AWS for deploying my website contents and am using windows machine

**Things I did**

1)I use zend pdt for development and i have configured by the pem file via ssh

2)Checked whether files which is getting uploaded and inside the var/www/html  folder

3)I have created all the folder /var/www/html via linux commands using Mobaxterm

4)I have changed the permission by chmod 777 for the folder

Finally i have tried the commands also

- sudo adduser gs www-data
- sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
- sudo chmod -R g+rw /var/www

**Problem Statement**

When i try to access the files via browser its not getting loaded http://54.191.190.17/c.html

Is there any steps which i missed , Kindly tell me a right step to follow to get it launched

Comment: Are you using ec2? Which web server you have installed?

Comment: Are you getting a 404? or an error page from the webserver? Are you able to get any page from the webserver? ( so you can reach it via the browser?)

Comment: @M.M. and Adam Ocsvari i have got it worked , the directory structure is formed with out permission thats the reason for this now its working http://54.191.190.17/c.html

Comment: Can you then answer the question and mark your answer?

Comment: /home/ubuntu/var/www/html should be the place where we load the files as root user , What i have did i have created directory by moving to /var/www/html (i.e i traversed back from /home/ubuntu to /home/ and then to / ) and i made the directory there so i couldn't able to get it up , can i write this mistake as answer  or anyother way to write kindly @M.M. suggest